# Why is Google maps enforcing the "sensor" parameter?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

The [Google maps geocoding API](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding) has a `sensor` parameter that is [mandatory in V3](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingResponses):

> sensor (required) — Indicates whether or not the geocoding request comes from a device with a location sensor. This value must be either true or false.

requests without it are denied:

> "REQUEST_DENIED" indicates that your request was denied, generally because of lack of a sensor parameter.

Why is this? Why do they want to know so badly whether the request comes from a client with a sensor or not?

Is it for statistical reasons, or to be able to provide services in the future?

Comment: I could take a guess, but the only people really able to answer this would be Google employees that are working on the project.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The sensor parameter is required by Google as they need this information for statistics as part of their licensing terms with their data providers.

Taken [from this Google Groups post](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/79b3a63335494e2e) (from a Google employee by the looks of it)

> The sensor parameter doesn't  give you
>   any geo location capabilities it just
>   lets us know as part of  our licensing
>   terms with our data providers that the
>   map is being used in  conjunction with
>   some sort of geo location
>   functionality.

Answer (score 3):

The Google Maps docs have been updated and as of June 2014 and the `&sensor` parameter is no longer required for JavaScript or Web Service API calls. The parameter will now be ignored if passed along with any request.

[Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).

Comment: Section from the docs where they call out its removal: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?csw=1#Sensor